# How to get the list of followers in Pinterest?

Tags: python, ajax, pinterest

I need to get the list of all (or at least some) of followers/following of a specific user in Pinterest? You can see the list of followers in browser like this:
[https://www.pinterest.com/{user_name}/followers/](https://www.pinterest.com/%7Busername%7D/followers)

Pinterest is using Ajax to load the list of followers/following and I can not find the usernames in HTML source code of the page. Any idea how to crawl it?

Comment: Have you looked at their [API documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/)?

Comment: They don't provide followers/following data through the API.

Comment: @Hamooni can you let me know how you created the APP and authenticated it. I am facing issue in app approval

Answer (score 1):

A few options that come to mind:

1. You can use the Pinterest API
2. You can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/), it's even possible to use it headless with xvfb on Linux or phantomJS